# MySQL not properly matching email addresses using = but works with LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

It look like my problem is very common issue but my issue looks varied. That's why please accept my apology in advance.

Problem:
Im trying to write simple select query for example:

```
SELECT * from mytable where email_varchar = 'myemail@email.com'
```

Result = 0

When Run this SQL:

```
SELECT * from mytable where email_varchar Like '%myemail@email.com%'
```

it return result:
MYEMAIL@EMAIL.COM

(LIKE) i can't use because from this query im trying to updating my (bounced back) emails in my database. Records volume approximately 15k to 15.5k, so there is possibility emails match one or more records with 'like' clause.

Some failed attempts:

1. Attempt 
   `SELECT * from mytable where email_varchar = upper('myemail@email.com')`

=>Result = 0

2. Attempt `SELECT * from mytable where upper(email_varchar) = upper('myemail@email.com')`

=>Result = 0

3.Attempt `SELECT * from mytable where STRCMP(email_varchar, 'myemail@email.com') = 0`

=>Result = 0

4.Attempt `SELECT * from mytable where trim(email_varchar) = trim('myemail@email.com')`

=>Result = 0

5. Attempt `SELECT * from mytable where trim(upper(email_varchar)) = trim(upper('myemail@email.com'))`

=>Result = 0

Comment: What does `SELECT HEX(email_varchar) FROM mytable WHERE email_varchar LIKE '%myemail@email.com%'` produce? I think you have other junk in your field

Comment: @tadman thanks for quick response.  i checked nothing is there .... is there any other way. i can check more closely i can't see anything  when im doing normal select..

Comment: Have you tried `LIKE 'myemail@email.com'` without percent signs.

Comment: just tried result 0 ...

Comment: There has to be something there, even if it's invisible. That's why I'm asking *specifically* for the output of `HEX()`. The result in your example should be `6D79656D61696C40656D61696C2E636F6D`.

Comment: Could you search for non ascii characters?  SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE NOT email_varachar REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9@.]';

Comment: @tadman you are right... something else also there... where im pulling data HEX '6E406E6F2E636F6D'  result  and where im updating data, it is showing '4E404E4F2E434F4D0D' it is not same so what is the solution ??

Comment: Well, that's `N@NO.COM\r`. Why are there linefeed characters (0x0D) in there? If you can track down the origin of those and also remove them from your data using `REPLACE()` you'll probably find your matches are working.

Comment: @Joel thanks for reply almost all records :(

Comment: You can use an update statement to nuke out all the unwanted characters.

Comment: @tadman targeted database(where im trying to update) normally i  import from CSV file. maybe because of that ??

Comment: If you're on a machine that's LF only (e.g. Linux, OS X, BSD) and your source file is from Windows (CR+LF) you may get these. Convert the file before using it, or see if you can process it as a Windows source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cleaning out all the unwanted carriage return characters:

```
UPDATE mytable SET email_varchar = TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM email_varchar)
```

Note: I hope your column name isn't literally that, as having `_varchar` repeated endlessly in my queries would drive me up the wall.

Comment: no its not im just writing here to show its varchar :)  @tadman is there anyway without updating my database i can use in where clause.

Comment: You *really* want to update your database. Having dirty data and then working around it later just fossilizes the problem. `LIKE` queries are notoriously expensive as well, it requires scanning the entire table to produce matches. A properly indexed table can do this effortlessly.

Comment: You know what ???? you are Great ...... IT IS WORKING>>>>>>> i just ran you given update query ....

Comment: one last question is there anyway i can do this while importing CSV file in mySQL ?? my database on Linux

Comment: There's the [`fromdos` command](http://superuser.com/questions/52044/convert-crlfs-to-line-feeds-on-linux) to convert the file before importing.

Comment: This what im using right now                                                          `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'CSVFILE.txt'
INTO TABLE DataTableName
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES`

Comment: If you're not converting the file, `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` should help.